# get values from one class to another class - php

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes in php. class A and class B. In class A i have multiple functions and I want to call the functions of class A in class B and get the values in class B. Here are the classes:

Class A:

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class A {
    /**
     * Undocumented variable
     *
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client;
    public function __construct()
        {
                $apikey = '000000000000000';
                $this->client = new Client([
                'base_uri'=>'https://api.omnivore.io/',
                'headers'  => [
                'Api-Key'=>$apikey,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                            ]
                ]);

        }
    public function getMerchant(){
        $response = $this->client->request('GET','locations');
        $output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $merchants = json_decode($output, true);   
    }

    public function getMenu(){
        $response = $this->client->request('GET','locations/iE7EBzbT/menu');
        $output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $menu = json_decode($output, true); 

    }

}
```

Class B:

```
<?php

    class B
    {
        protected $client;
        public function index() {
            $apiClient = new A();
            $app = $apiClient->getMerchant();
           print_r($app) ;
        }

    }
    ?>
```

So, the question is how I can get the values of merchant in class B in index function. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: your classes are in seperate PHP files?

Comment: yes. there are two files

Comment: Unless you are using an autoloader, you'd need to require the file with class A when invoking (instantiating) it in class B. Obviously, it would help if you return a value from the function `getMerchant()` as noted by @Cid

Answer (score 2):

There is no `return` in `getMerchant()`. Doing `$app = $apiClient->getMerchant();` is a non sense, then.

You might want to do

**class A**

```
public function getMerchant(){
    $response = $this->client->request('GET','locations');
    $output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $merchants = json_decode($output, true);
    return $merchants; // <---- this
}
```

Comment: I did it. but still did not get anything

Comment: @HarisKhan if you are using a framework such as Symfony, you might want to clear the cache

Comment: because class B does not know of the existence of class A, you need to require (or include) it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use function from one class to another class.
you have to use inheritance concept.

This principle will affect the way many classes and objects relate to one another. For example, when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class.

Please refer Link:- https://php5-tutorial.com/classes/inheritance/

Class B:

```
<?php

    class B extends A
    {
        protected $client;
        public function index() {
            $apiClient = new A();
            $app = $apiClient->getMerchant();
           print_r($app) ;
        }

    }
```

?>

Comment: Use like this
` <?php
Class A{
    function getMerchant(){
        if(method_exists($this, 'index')){
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
Class B extends A{
    function index(){
        echo 'Welcome';
    }
}
$test = new B();
$test->getMerchant();
?>`